# How to bring back column names from a view but change the names to these columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

Hi I'm currently using the below query to bring back the column names from my view:

```
 select column_name as Description, column_name as Value
 from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
 where TABLE_NAME = 'vw_document_main'
```

This will return all the column names from my table, but say for instance I want system_status to read as System Status, how can I achieve this without actually updating the view itself?

I'm assuming I can use an AS clause somewhere, just not sure where. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: `system_status` is a value in `column_name`, correct?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have space on the column name, delimit it by enclosing on brackets, eg

```
SELECT system_status AS [System Status], ...
```